# Filtering dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which has information on 1000 stocks (open, close, high , low, volume, company name, ticker symbol  etc.) and I have another dataframe which just has one column of ticker symbols and this second dataframe has fewer rows than 1000 rows in the first dataframe. Now, I want only those rows in the first dataframe for which the ticker symbol is available in the second dataframe. How can this be done using pandas ? In my case, I have small dataframes. But I would also like to know how this operation can be scaled up. So, please suggest efficient way as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to filter to the list of tickers available in df2.

```
df1_filtered = df1[df1['ticker'].isin(df2['ticker'].tolist())]
```